# jQuery - Using touchmove to hide menubar but show again if no longer sliding

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, touchmove

I have the following code:-

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel touchmove', function (e) {
      if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY) { //alternative options for wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
        //scroll down
        console.log('Down');
        $( ".navbar" ).addClass( "hide-nav-bar" );
      } else {
        //scroll up
        console.log('Up');
        $( ".navbar" ).removeClass( "hide-nav-bar" );
      }
      //prevent page fom scrolling
      //return false;
    });
```

**CSS**

```
    .navbar {
        -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.7s .3s ease;
           -moz-transition:   -moz-transform 0.7s .3s ease;
            -ms-transition:    -ms-transform 0.7s .3s ease;
                transition:        transform 0.7s .3s ease;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
       -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    .navbar.hide-nav-bar{
       -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
       -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
       -ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
       transform: translate(0, -100%);
       -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
```

I am using fullPage.js and this is working fine on desktop, when I scroll to the next page is hides the menu, and if I stop sliding the menu animated back into it's fixed position.

On mobile, when I scroll down the menu hides as expected but the navbar is permanently gone (i.e. removeClass("hide-nav-bar") is never fired).

Is there a way to bring back the menu if the user stops scrolling on a mobile device?

EDIT:

Actually, adding `e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY` to work on mobile devices stops it from working on desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT be using your own event handler. 
Fullpage.js provides callbacks such as [`onLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction) or [`afterLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) to deal with all of that. And they will work on touch devices as well.

Touch functionality is much complicated in fullpage.js than the mouse events.

You should be using something of this kind:

```
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        var loadedSection = $(this);

        //using index
        if(index > 1){
             $( ".navbar" ).addClass( "hide-nav-bar" );
        }

        else{
            $( ".navbar" ).removeClass( "hide-nav-bar" );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I decided to change the script so it detects if the user is active or not which now works on mobile/desktop:-

```
var timeoutID;

function setup() {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
}
setup();

function startTimer() {
    // wait 2 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 1000);
}

function resetTimer(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);

    goActive();
}

function goInactive() {
    $( ".navbar" ).addClass( "hide-nav-bar" );
}

function goActive() {
    $( ".navbar" ).removeClass( "hide-nav-bar" );   
    startTimer();
}
```

Comment: Not the way to go for it. Check out my answer.